# Ping latency vs location on a map (x kilometer of a trip) | ping-latency vs distance

Tags: ping, gsm, gps

Orange is having problem delivering the internet between biggest cities (I'm traveling via train). There are white spots on the way...

They do not see the problem, so I thought - lets make a chart
**ping-latency vs distance (location on map)**

Do you know any tool that could provide this statistics? 
I have a Gobi 3000 GSM/GPS modem.

Comment: Internet distance may not be linear or relative to your physical location.

Answer (score 0):

The quick working solution with my GOBI 3000 GSM/GPS modem

via:
https://sigquit.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/enabling-gps-location-in-modemmanager/

My raw data (note that output is empty when there is no signal - that was my inital problem, since I was configuring at home :) )

```
-------------------------
Raw GPS | UTC time: '214259.0'
| Longitude: '16,92xxxx'
| Latitude: '52,45xxxx'
| Altitude: '75,300000'
```

I need to write a script that would both ping and store the gps position, and then process it a bit. I hope to past the solution soon.

```
pseudocode:    
ping google.com -c 1 >> somefile
gpspipe -w -n 10 |grep -e Longitude -e Latitude >> somefile
(then plot it)
```